# What is the limit for pairing batteries in series? What happens if we cross that limit?

Tags: batteries, current, high-voltage, charging, efficiency

Can we simply keep pairing more and more batteries in series configuration to produce higher and higher voltages? What are the consequences in doing so? Would the power from others series cells be enough to fry the battery at the end during the discharge cycle or fry the first battery during the charge cycle? How would the energy be transferred from one cell to another in such configuration as a cell has a seperating layer (the electrolyte) would the electrolyte degraded quicker because of such huge power transfers? In general, what is the physics behind this arrangement?

**Edit**
So my understanding is in a serious connection the postive terminal is connected to a negative terminal, and in a cell both terminals are separated by an electrolyte which only allows the motions of positive ions and restricts the flow of electrons accross it, so now question is wouldn't the first battery's electrolyte be subjected to much higher power transfer accross it's electrolyte compared to the other batteries ? Wouldn't it?

Comment: Seen 30 12V batteries in series - no issues. Any battery just adds its voltage to the existing voltage. So if you need to disconnect batteries that produce 380V DC then start at the negative ir grounded end.

Comment: the various electric vehicles have big strings of cells in series. The have balancing hardware to ensure the voltage across each cell does not exceed a given amount which would occur if a cell failed. Even with an infinite string, each cell only supplies what it can so there no huge energy transfer in excess of what a single cell can do. However the big issue when drawing or charging large amounts of current from a cell is heating. You'll see companies like Tesla put significant effort into thermal management of the batteries.

Comment: Success rate for any serial system is proportional to  1/(1-f)^n where f is failure rate and n is number of serial elements. You can mitigate this if you can bypass defective cells.

Comment: See [Zamboni Piles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zamboni_pile)

Comment: I've seen a 2 kV battery made by clipping 9V rectangular batteries in series. The MIT safety office was not pleased with the grad student who constructed it ツ

Comment: 90 volt carbon-zinc batteries were commonplace for portable radios in the vacuum tube era. They provided B+ plate voltage and they were called B batteries, of course. I last had my hands on one in current production in the late 1960s. It was included in an educational cloud chamber kit. Momentary connection cleared particle tracks from the chamber.

Comment: The edit is better as a separate question, how power is measured. In short: you can come up with any measure for local power you like, say a 1A current flow beside a 1MV voltage drop: is that 1MW? Who knows, unless you're dropping that current through that *exact* voltage drop, it's just theoretical. In the battery case, only the 1.5V drop per cell is meaningful to the cell.

Answer (score 12):

The limit is whatever the insulation surrounding the batteries can handle.

If you have one million 1.5 V batteries, then it is perfectly possible to put all of them in series, thereby creating a 1,500,000 V battery. However, if the two terminals are too close to each other, or to the ground, or to anything else conductive, the air will undergo [electrical breakdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_breakdown) and create an electric arc. It'll be a little bit like lightning striking.

At such high voltages, both ends of the 1,500,000 volt battery will also undergo [corona discharge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corona_discharge). I don't know how much current this will consume.

None of the individual 1.5 V cells will experience anything unusual. Each cell only experiences a voltage of 1.5 V, which is completely normal. The amount of current going through each cell will probably not exceed the short-circuit current of the cells (for alkaline AA cells, about 10 A). The amount of *power* being conveyed through each cell is completely irrelevant and has no effects whatsoever.

Comment: This is the crux of the problem. Everybody gets comfortable working around nice, docile 5 or 12 volts DC, and thinks "well surely higher DC voltages are my friend too, they can't be any worse than mains AC which is pretty safe" (because of massive engineering done behind the curtain).  No. At higher DC voltages it cannot be bargained with, cannot be reasoned with, does not know pity or remorse or fear and absolutely will not stop, ever.  If you doubt me, take any relay and compare its AC to DC rating lol.

Answer (score 5):

As long as the battery management keeps all the cells balanced, none of them will experience any kind of anomalous voltage or power.

The limit would be dielectric breakdown between the most positive and most negative terminal. But I am not aware of any application which even gets close to this limit.

Answer (score 3):

> how would the energy be transferred from one cell to another in such
> configuration as a cell has a seperating layer (the electrolyte) would
> the electrolyte degraded quicker because of such huge power transfers
> ?

Under normal conditions each cell produces the same voltage it would in a smaller battery. Therefore the power consumed per cell is the same and the electrolyte will degrade no faster.

However if a cell becomes over-discharged or overcharged before the others then it could potentially get the combined voltage of all the other cells across it during discharge, or the peak charger voltage minus the voltage of the other cells during charging, resulting in high power consumption and rapid electrolyte degradation.

You don't need a lot of cells in series for this to be a problem. Even with only a few cells the equipment might not notice the voltage anomaly when one cell is overcharged or over-discharged while the others are still providing good voltage.